# How to modify result of @Formula ComposeWithReference in fresh new notesuidocument

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I am modifying the mail9.ntf, in order to have User A answer to create a response to an email, on behalf of a generic user (owner B) of the mail file.
When composing a response to an email, the template use the following code:

```
REM {Notes Style Reply with History};
tmp:=From;
@SetEnvironment("fwdID"; @NoteID);
@Command([ComposeWithReference];"":"";"Memo"; 23 + 64);
```

Its works OK, but:
if there was an attachment in the original email, the following sentence is added:

```
[attachment "MyAttachment.odt" deleted by User A/MyDomain]
```

Server Domino 9.0.1FP10 - Notes 9.0.1FP7.

I tried to use the postopen event in order to use the Source notesuidocument to parse the body field and retrieve the line:
    [attachment "MyAttachment.odt" deleted by User A/MyDomain]

but:
at this stage (new document, berver saved before), notesuidocument do not contains anything.

```
Source.getfieldText("body") return nothing
```

I do not have an fhandle on the contains.

I expect to be able to remove part of the new composed message from the body field.

Comment: Option A would be to create the new email with lotuscript and handle the stripping of the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the flag value of 16 is designed explicitly so the user can't delete that text because the assumption is that you want a record of who deleted the attachment. If your code ccould do it, a user who is editing the document could do it, too.

You're probably going to have to remove it using back-end code going through PostClose events. There may be a temporary NotesItem holding that information that you can delete before that, perhaps in QuerySave. You'll have to go through the items in memory in order to figure that out.

Another option is dropping the 16 option from your flags parameter (7+64) and writing code to delete the attachments yourself.